# How to get disk I/O activity by files and processes?

Tags: linux, process, disk, io

On Red Hat 8 I sometimes get huge disk I/O operations.

I can see disk I/O activities by using `sudo iotop -oP` command.

Output is:

```
PID | USER | DISK READ | DISK WRITE
---- ------ ----------- -----------
342   user1    200 MB/s      5 MB/s
```

What I would like is to get full file path that does the disk I/Os.

```
PID | USER | DISK READ | DISK WRITE | FILE
---- ------ ----------- ------------ ------------------------
342   user1    193 MB/s      2 MB/s  /home/user1/file1.txt
342   user1      5 MB/s      2 MB/s  /home/user1/file2.txt
342   user1      2 MB/s      1 MB/s  /home/user1/file3.txt
```

In this case I see file1.txt is the culprit of disk usage.

What I would like to get is above list as sum of last 5 seconds disk activity by files for every 5 seconds.

Comment: The block drivers only see devices and block addresses, no files. So it's rather unlikely that a command can do that. However once you know the program, you can use `lsof` to fine the files of that program, and then in turn, try an `strace` for a specific file handle of such process.

Comment: I would like to have DISK READ and WRITE per MB/s for files. The closes that I have found is filetop command https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/filetop_example.txt - but I would need full file path for FILE.

Comment: So I guess you'll have to hack the sources (and widen your terminal ;-))